# Animating ScrollTop for side navigation for single page anchors

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, navigation, scrolltop

I'm trying to animated a smooth transition between anchor point on a single page with a stationary navigation on the side that gets highlighted. I'm a complete novice so I don't know how to implement "( document.body ).animate" or what ever is necessary to do the transitions.

tl;dr:
smooth scroll to anchors instead of jumping to anchors

here is the js:

```
$('#firstlink').addClass('active');

$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('.active').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });

    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();


    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) 
        $('#fifthlink').addClass('active');
    else if (scrollTop > $("#fifth").position().top)
        $('#fifthlink').addClass('active');
    else if (scrollTop > $("#fourth").position().top)
        $('#fourthlink').addClass('active');
    else if (scrollTop > $("#third").position().top)
        $('#thirdlink').addClass('active');
    else if (scrollTop > $("#second").position().top)
        $('#secondlink').addClass('active');
    else
        $('#firstlink').addClass('active');
});
```

here is the complete jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e03u0kqe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was probably answered somewhere else but this should do it:

```
    $('#sidenav a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).attr('href');
        var scrollTo = $(target).offset().top;
        var duration = 1000;

        $('body').animate({
            scrollTop: scrollTo 
        }, duration);
    });
```

Add it after your window scroll event.

https://jsfiddle.net/e03u0kqe/2/

Answer (score 1):

This may be of use to you:

http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/quick-guide-adding-smooth-scrolling-to-your-webpages/

I use it in my own site, and it works pretty well.

Hope this is of use to you.